# split file in Linux error "invalid number of bytes"

Tags: linux, unix

When I use `--line-bytes` with `split`, do I need to declare the size of the file? I am doing as per `split`'s `man page` but I am getting an error. What am I doing wrong?

I want to break each file by size 112640.

```sh
split -a 10 --line-bytes= 112640 "$temp_compress_dir/$local_tmp_file" $temp_compress_dir/$myhost.$local_tmp_file.split.
```

I get error:

```
split: : invalid number of bytes
```

Comment: what about the blank after `=`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the space after your equals sign:

```
split -a 10 --line-bytes=112640 "$temp_compress_dir/$local_tmp_file" $temp_compress_dir/$myhost.$local_tmp_file.split.
```

Comment: ...and lesson learned for me: don't test this in your home directory with `--line-bytes=1`... !

Comment: can I put --line-bytes=127MB?

Comment: @Riomario - yes you can use `127M` or `127MB` as per the man page:
_The SIZE argument is an integer and optional unit (example: 10K is 10*1024).  Units are K,M,G,T,P,E,Z,Y (powers of 1024) or KB,MB,.. (powers of 1000)_

Answer (score 0):

When you specify an option in Linux with the "=" equal sign there is no space

```
--line-bytes=112640
```

And when there is no "=" equal sign there is a space

```
-a 10
```

Comment: can I put --line-bytes=127MB?